# When React component loaded initially i am getting values as undefined which are coming from reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When React component loaded initially i am getting values as undefined  which are coming from reducer.

Here is my code

```
const [componentState, dispatchComponentState] = useReducer(
versionReducer,
```

)

Here is my reducer Versionreducer File.

```
const initialState = {
  
  version:'',
  detail:''
}

const versionReducer = (state = initialState, newState) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    ...newState,
  }
}

export default versionReducer
```

From above reducer i am accessing componentState?.version , componentState?.detail
in my component but i am getting these values as undefined instead of ''.

Whats the issue here ?

Comment: Could you please add a larger code snippet, showing your whole component. From the provided code it's impossible to know exactly what your problem is

Comment: What is the second argument of your `useReducer` hook?

Answer (score 0):

try to declare hook like  this

```
const initialState = {
  
  version:'',
  detail:''
}

const versionReducer = (newState , state = initialState) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    ...newState,
  }
}

export default versionReducer
```

and now call it like this

```
const [componentState, dispatchComponentState] = useReducer(
versionReducer
)
```

before you were passing the state but it was storing it into state variable and nothing was going tp newState as you were passing only one peremeter  thats why you were getting undefined as that value will not be changed ,

change all the functions according to i did and it will surely work...if not do comment.